"Inaccurate Content in Literary Analysis"
I've received a couple of literary analyses that quotes dialogue and refers to events in the short story that literally doesn't occur. How does one evaluate such submissions?

What, are you teaching them?

Are they generated by an AI bot like ChatGPT? In any case, it seems like these analyses are answers to a question you didn't ask, and so should result in a poor grade.

What are the relevant policies in your syllabus?

Related: Is it plagiarism to reference a fictitious source?
